# How to wait for destruction of Python object

Tags: python

Is there a way to tell when the destructor of an object has been called by the garbage collector? I need to know this because of some network resources I need right after a destructor frees them. For example, the destructor deletes a virtual network interface that might be added again right away. This of course leads to problems when the interface is re-added before it is deleted by the destructor. The necessary resource frees happen in the `__del__(self)` function of the object representing the virtual network.

```
def __del__(self):
        print("Deconstructing " + self.devName)
           [...]
        sub.call(["ip", "link", "delete", self.devName])
        sub.call(["pkill", "dnsmasq"])
        try:
            os.remove("/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases")
        except:
            "No dhcp leases to delete"
```

Comment: You can delete it manually?

Comment: Most objects in CPython are not garbage collected, but reference counted. Unless you have cyclic references, when there are no more references to an object it will be deleted (note that using `del` does not guarantee that the object will be deleted, since there may still be other references to it). If you control the references to the object you should know precisely when `__del__` happens. In any case, it may not be a good idea to rely on `__del__` for this, maybe you could use a context manager, or at least specific methods to issue these OS commands.

Comment: If you are trying to do RAII in Python, you want to look up the `with` statement, which uses `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions. https://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm